# Python 3.8.2 cannot find the modules I installed with pip when I run the code form VS Code. But when I run the code from Terminal it works

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, module, pip

This happened with csv23 and decouple modules today.

Here is my system information :

```
ozgurbuldum@Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro ~ % which -a pip
/Users/ozgurbuldum/.pyenv/shims/pip
/Users/ozgurbuldum/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip

ozgurbuldum@Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro ~ % which -a python
python: aliased to python3
/Users/ozgurbuldum/.pyenv/shims/python
/usr/bin/python
/Users/ozgurbuldum/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

ozgurbuldum@Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro ~ % which -a python3
/Users/ozgurbuldum/.pyenv/shims/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/Users/ozgurbuldum/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Suggested solutions to similar questions did not work for me.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

With love,
Oz

Comment: Run this command in Terminal and VSCode internal terminal : `type python`, do you have the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the same python interpreter across all platforms!
Specify to vscode which interpreter you are using (you can change the python interpreter).
Use the same interpreter you use for vscode in your terminal or the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check your interpreter in vscode.
I too suffered the same. Then I check my interpreter in vscode. I was working on wrong interpreter.[checkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XytZ.png)

or try to install pip3 (install your module)